# Discord API: Missing Permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Today, I debugged my code. However, when I get to the point where I remove the bot's permissions I got an error, "Discord API: Missing Permissions". Therefore, I tried something out to make the bot check if it has the required permission. But when I tried the code below, I got an error again saying, "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined"

```
   if (!client.permissions.has('SEND_MESSAGES')) {
      return;
    }
```

Comment: What class is `client`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So start by listening to the error message like it's your top "confidential informant"

Here's what it's saying to you:

> cannot read property XXXXX of 'undefined'

So look at the message - XXXXX equates to "has" and that means *undefined* is equivalent to *client.permissions*

Why is that value undefined at this point?